# Qt SQL `nextResult` function for MySQL Server 8.0: delayed execution per result set?

Tags: mysql, performance, qt

We are currently doing a lot of small queries. We execute a query, read the results, and then execute the next one. Since network requests cost a lot of time, this ping-ponging gets slow very fast.

This is why we want to do multiple queries at once, sending all data that the SQL server must know to it, and only retrieving one result (consisting of multiple result sets).

We found that Qt 5.14.1's QSqlQuery has the `nextResult()` function, but in the documentation ([link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#nextResult)) it says:

> Some databases may execute all statements at once **while others may delay the execution until the result set is actually accessed**, [...].

**MY QUESTION:**

**So, does MySql Server 8.0 delay the execution until the result set is actually accessed?** If this is the case, then we still have a ping-pong for every query right? Which would be very slow still.

P.S. Our current solution to just have 1 ping-pong is to union different result sets (resulting in kind of a block diagonal matrix) with lots and lots of null values), and this question is meant to find a better way to do this.

Comment: If network requests 'take a lot of time' how does any MySQL server ever have 700 Connections per second?  We should probably look at your 'workload' will post additional information requests in about an hour. Thanks

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Try a few `SELECT SLEEP(2);` statements.  It should be obvious whether it waits until the end.  Then Answer your own Question.  Are you using a Stored Procedure?  Or what?